# Disable a link until countdown is over Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a link which is like this:

```
<a  class="modal-button" id="submitLink" >
```

once i click on it a jquery code gets executed and sends an ajax call to my server. I have made a countdown that if ajax call is not successful will showup and I want to disable the link unless countdown is over. How can I do that with jquery?

Here is the countdown code:

```
function countdown(duration, display) {
var timer = duration, seconds;
setInterval(function () {

seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

display.text("Try again in "+ seconds);

if (--timer < 0) {
  display.text("Done");
  return;
}
}, 1000);
}
```

and this is my click event:

```
$('#submitLink').on("click",function(){


$('#submit-text').html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i>');
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "something.php",
  data: {somedata},
  success: function(data)
  {  var data= JSON.parse(data).data;

    countdown(15,$('#submit-text'));

  }
});

});
```

Comment: Well on a normal link you could only add the href till after the countdown

Comment: @Manu but I'm using ajax and with href that is not possible

Comment: @HiradRoshandel `but I'm using ajax and with href that is not possible` What???

Comment: @A.Wolff how will you do it?

Comment: @HiradRoshandel I cannot help more without seeing countdown code relevant part

Comment: @A.Wolff I edited my post

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have added my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I used A.Wolf answer to fix it this way. I added a data attribute with a boolean value:

```
 <a  class="modal-button" id="submit" data-disabled="false">
```

every time link is clicked i checked if it's true or false. If it's true return otherwise execute ajax. Then set it to true in ajax success and at the of timer set it back to false;

Comment: This is better than my answer using a class imho

Answer (score 1):

You could add a class e.g `disabled` to anchor element:

```
<a  class="modal-button disabled" id="submitLink">ajax link</a>
```

Then use following logic in `coutdown()` method:

```
function countdown(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration,
        seconds;
    var interval = setInterval(function () {

        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        display.text("Try again in " + seconds);

        if (--timer < 0) {
            display.text("Done");
            clearInterval(interval);
            $('#submitLink').removeClass('disabled');
            return;
        }
    }, 1000);
};
```

And bind handler delegating it to process selector on the fly:

```
$(document).on('click', '#submitLink:not(.disabled)', function () {
    $('#submit-text').html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i>');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "something.php",
        data: {
            somedata
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var data = JSON.parse(data).data;
            $('#submit-text').addClass('disabled');
            countdown(15, $('#submit-text'));

        }
    });
});
```

This is just one way, there is many ways on achieving your expected behaviour.

Comment: "disabled" doesn't prevent it from being clicked

Comment: @HiradRoshandel I use a class filtered by selector `'#submitLink:not(.disabled)'`, not the disabled attribute

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below:

```
var ajaxCallInProgress = false;

$('#submitLink').on("click",function(){
    if(ajaxCallInProgress) {
        return false;
    }
    $('#submit-text').html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i>');
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
       url: "something.php",
       data: {somedata},
       beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
          ajaxCallInProgress = true;
       },
       success: function(data)
       {  
           var data= JSON.parse(data).data;
           countdown(15,$('#verify-text'));
          $('#submit-text').text('Done');
           ajaxCallInProgress = false;
       }
    });

});
```

Comment: I tried it but didn't work. I have added my code can you take a look please.

Comment: Updated my answer. Please have a look and let me know if this works!

Comment: the problem is I want it to wait 15 seconds after each ajax. I think your code doesn't do anything with the countdown it just doesn't let you click in between calls

Comment: You can easily do that by adding `ajaxCallInProgress = false;` in `countdown` method when it's done. Also remove  `ajaxCallInProgress = false;` line from above code I have provided. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

1. A click-Event starts the Countdown and the AJAX Request (with a
   hight timeout)
2. The server generates the Link and hold the Connection
   X seconds until he send the Request (the generated link), so nobody
   can manipulate the Timer
3. If the Request is successful, the href must
   be replaced by the generated link
4. If the countdown ends first, an
   error message must be shown

The countdown should be 2 or 3 seconds longer than the server holds the connections

Answer (score 0):

**solution:**

Remove the link on click

```
$('#submitLink').on("click",function(){
    $(this).removeAttr("href");
});
```

Add a link

```
$("#submitLink").attr("href", "path/to/somewhere.html");
```

Comment: I cant remove the a tag it ruins the design

Comment: use $("#submitLink").removeAttr("href");